# Sharepoint 2013 - Can't change theme using change the look

Tags: sharepoint, themes

I have been working on creating a custom .spcolor file to update our company color scheme to our Sharepoint site. I have noticed that when I try to use the Change the Look feature to change the theme to one of the default themes, it doesn't change when I hit the Try it Out link.

After researching further, I noticed that the issue only occurs with the Seattle site layout and not Oslo.

I tried to look at the Seattle masterpages and the css files associated, but didn't see anything unusual. I am a novice at Sharepoint, so maybe this is just something easy I am not finding.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The difference between `Seattle` and `Oslo` masterpages is the `CssRegistration` control :

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" EnableCssTheming="true" />
```

So the `Seattle` masterpage is missing the `EnableCssTheming="true"` attribute which fix everyting.